# Is there a way to sort questions in answers.ros personal inbox?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to sort questions in  answers.ros personal inbox? I can sort by date if I view all questions but the option does not appear when viewing my inbox .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204849/is-there-a-way-to-sort-questions-in--answers.ros-personal-inbox?/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that's an option. I suggest you make a request upstream on askbot. https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-17**:
I've posted a request to Askboy